# eset nod32 gui freezes during load

Tags: anti-virus, freeze, nod32

I have been using ESET NOD32 anti-virus without problem for quite some time now, but just recently the egui page of it has started freezing (the splash screen never goes away). If I kill the process and start it again the same thing happens again.

I've looked in the windows event logs, but there are no errors in there.

I'm running Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.

Is there somewhere else I can look for the cause of this?

Comment: have you installed anything new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virus db is updated all the time, but not the ESET application. Download the latest version from [here](http://www.eset.com/download/business-64bit.php) and install.
I can only assume it doesn't update itself automatically in case a malicious script did this and replaced the exe with something benign.

Comment: I've uninstalled an re-installed it, and all is well again.

Answer (score 1):

Eset Nod32 looks for malicious activity as soon as you windows is done loading driver.

> - A possibility is that you have some malicious software in your start-up
>     and your anti-virus is checking it to
>     make sure you are safe.
> - Another possibility is that nod32 works very slowly if you installed any
>     conflicting softwares like new
>     anti-virus or any new anti-spyware
>     program

**To Remove Splash Screen at the program startup (ESET NOD32 Antivirus and ESET Smart Security)**

> In ESET NOD32 Antivirus, or ESET Smart
>   Security, navigate to the Advanced
>   setup screen, select the branch User
>   interface and disable the option Show
>   splash-screen at startup.

**To Remove Splash Screen at the program startup (ESET NOD32 only Antivirus)**

> Open NOD32 Control Center > NOD32
>   System Tools > NOD32 System Setup >
>   Setup. In the General tab, tick the
>   checkbox „Do not display NOD32 splash
>   screen at startup“.

Comment: thanks, i've turned off the splash screen. after having re-installed it all.